# Rails5, Webpacker and webpacker dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

I run an web app localhost using Rails5, Puma webserver, and forwardHQ for my localhost testing, such that fizzbuzz.dev is the Internet address. My webpack+React App renders and the Chrome dev console is relatively clean if I use Webpack 3 to compile things on the fly, no dev server. If I switch to using a Procfile.dev and foreman with the line:

```
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

the App continues to run, but the console fills with XHR calls to some sockjs-node/info call that fails. Maybe 4 or 5 of those. What are they? Is that something I should care about? It seems my App runs nonetheless, but a messy console is not something I like.

Any tips on how to fix it so this bad XHR calls turns into a success? What would change if it did work?

My webpacker yaml setup is:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
dev_server:
  https: true
  host: 0.0.0.0
  port: 3035
  public: 0.0.0.0:3035
  hmr: false
  # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
  inline: true
  overlay: true
  compress: true
  disable_host_check: true
  use_local_ip: false
  quiet: false
  headers:
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  watch_options:
    ignored: /node_modules/
```

I tried using localhost for 0.0.0.0, same result. Not sure how to resolve this. Tried without HTTPS too but that also failed.

Comment: Show us the failing logs, please.

Comment: Which logs specifically? Console? Rails? All I see in console are these... 

GET https://fizzbuzz.dev:3035/sockjs-node/info?t=1527309476931 0 ()

Comment: I meant more specific logs entries from the console that you are concerned about. Sounds like it could be related to this issue: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/829

Comment: I changed HMR to true and the same problem... with one extra log entry 

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

Comment: And this is not returning 404.. these XHR calls simply fail. Nothing is returned.